# CodeIgniter - Model autoload array order is affecting my application?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to create my first MVC application. I am trying to use the autoload library so I don't have to load my models all over the place. I have noticed that order in which I load the models in the array seems to really affect my program. This is my autoload array:

```
$autoload['model'] = array( 'one_model','two_model','three_model','four_model','five_model','six_model', 'seven_model', 'eight_model');
```

Now when I change the order to be:

```
$autoload['model'] = array( 'two_model','three_model','four_model','five_model','one_model','six_model', 'seven_model', 'eight_model');
```

I will get the error:

```
Severity: Notice 

Message: Undefined property: controllerthree::$seven_model
```

I have noticed that how I load the model array does error. I have read many different SO posts but haven't seen this answered anywhere and this may be because it shouldn't affect the order.

Comment: Can you post the code which is causing the error?

Comment: check your class name "seven_model"

may be sensitive case

Comment: @WRDev the names are fine. Like I said the application works perfectly until you change the order of the autoload array. I couldn't for the life of me understand this so I wanted to know if the order made some sort of difference.